# How to render reflections of emissive material of another object in react-three-fiber?

Tags: three.js, 3d, react-three-fiber

My scene is pretty simple. I have a (Ground) Plane and a sphere on top of it. I am setting an emissive material to the sphere. Now, I want reflection of the emitted light by the sphere on the plane.

Looks like that is not possible in a straight-forward way. (I totally wish THREE.js was like Maya or Blender). And from what I have looked around, point lights were suggested. But I am having a gradient emission map. So a point light will not satisfy my needs here.

Some other answers have suggested something on the lines of capturing the scene by a reflection surface and other have pointed me to cube camera rendering....I do not totally understand what they mean - am quite new to THREE.js and this low a level of graphics. Especially this answer to a beginner like me looks daunting (I am just starting to mess with shaders). [Emissive ligth and reflection in Three.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61219585/emissive-ligth-and-reflection-in-three-js)

If anyone can explain the method or provide resources where I can learn about them, I would be grateful.

Comment: I don’t know of an easier way to add reflections than by copying the mirror example mentioned in the answer you provided: https://threejs.org/examples/?q=mirror#webgl_mirror

Comment: I am having a custom shader on the ground plane. Would adding a mirror affect that? And I want a pretty glossy effect instead of perfect reflection.

Comment: In that case, it sounds like you have very specific requirements so you’ll have to write a custom solution yourself.

Comment: Any pointers on how to proceed though?

Comment: Ok I did some sorcery and I got it to work somehow.

Comment: I think I will post my method as an answer, so other people might find it useful - though chrome throws me a lot of errors (found that this is a bug with chrome itself)